# Facebook open graph - what is session secret and how to find it?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

can someone please enlighten me on what session secret is and how to find it?

Answer (score 0):

A session secret key is used for signing request to Facebook api functions. It is used in situations where it can be disclosed, for example in browser executed javascript code which makes API calls and needs to sign them.

Facebook have not yet provided a way to get a session secret key in the new graph API so you need to enable 'deprecated api methods' under your app settings and then you can use the old REST api call auth.promoteSession to get your session secret key server-side, then embed that key in the code to be used client-side.